# C++ function to count all the words in a string

Tags: c++, string

I was asked this during an interview and apparently it's an easy question but it wasn't and still isn't obvious to me.

Given a string, count all the words in it. Doesn't matter if they are repeated. Just the total count like in a text files word count. Words are anything separated by a space and punctuation doesn't matter, as long as it's part of a word.

For example: 
`A very, very, very, very, very big dog ate my homework!!!! ==> 11 words`

My "algorithm" just goes through looking for spaces and incrementing a counter until I hit a null. Since i didn't get the job and was asked to leave after that I guess My solution wasn't good? Anyone have a more clever solution? Am I missing something?

Comment: "until I hit a null" - how are nulls special in a string in C++?

Comment: @Cubbi: Well spotted. I did not join the dots there.

Comment: By the answers given below, it seems that more context is really required.  Some industries use "modern" C++, finding that the cost of using STL and boost more than makes up for the productivity gains.  Other industries prefer to use a more C-like version of C++ so that there's a more direct mapping of code lines to processor instructions.  Future answers to questions along these lines would be well served to determine at least the industry the candidate is applying to.

Comment: You have as much context as I do. The interviewer was not very cooperative and didn't give much feedback when I asked if he was looking for something clever or just brute force. While Martin gave a bad ass answer below and fantastic description, I really got the feeling from the interviewer that it was just a test to see if I could code something "basic". But then again I didn't get the offer so what do I know...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A less clever, more obvious-to-all-of-the-programmers-on-your-team method of doing it.

```
#include <cctype>

int CountWords(const char* str)
{
   if (str == NULL)
      return error_condition;  // let the requirements define this...

   bool inSpaces = true;
   int numWords = 0;

   while (*str != '\0')
   {
      if (std::isspace(*str))
      {
         inSpaces = true;
      }
      else if (inSpaces)
      {
         numWords++;
         inSpaces = false;
      }

      ++str;
   }

   return numWords;
}
```

Comment: Its relatively standard to use the stream operator >> to get words. I don't see how this is more obvious as it takes a while to read all this code and understand it.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: My bad. I don't see why immediately why it works but testing it on codepad seems to work. I think it's unintuitive though.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: I deleted my answer because I found some cases where it gives wrong answers. That said, I still think the design was more intuitive than this one.

Comment: It may be standard to use >> to get words, but for those of us who never deal with text files the standard is irrelevant.  The point of my opening statement is that this code requires only that the user understands very basic parts of the language.

Comment: @Billy intuitive is also a personal value.  :)  Regardless, we should all strive to avoid doing (virtually) the same check in multiple places, because it is a vector for errors.  Also- choosing names that impart meaning rather than state implementation details is helpful to future generations.

Comment: This is the answer I'd like to see as an interviewer. When asking someone to implement a trivial algorithm in an interview, the interviewer is usually trying to see if the person can write a piece of low-level code sanely without introducing unnecessary overhead, complexity, or obfuscation. They are not attempting to engage in a dick-measuring contest over obscure library features or challenge the interviewee to a game of code golf.

Comment: This is similar to what I had. Guess we would both be no hires for  that company. Lol.

Comment: Lol, +1 for not engaging in dick measuring contests!

Comment: That should be inSpaces=false towards the end. Did u test it?

Comment: @eviljack yes thanks.  I renamed the variable after posting to be more appropriate, and missed one spot.  sry.

Comment: @eviljack yeah I suspect that the requirements of my job and of Martin's are very different.

Comment: I don't know how to comment on edits but whoever changed the code in the "community" edit changed it so that it no longer met the requirements.

Comment: Why you did implicitly assume the string is a C-Style string?!

Answer (score 39):

Assuming words are white space separated:

```
unsigned int countWordsInString(std::string const& str)
{
    std::stringstream stream(str);
    return std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}
```

Note: There may be more than one space between words. Also this does not catch other white space characters like tab new line or carriage return. So counting spaces is not enough.

The stream input operator >> when used to read a string from a stream. Reads one white space separated word. So they were probably looking for you to use this to identify words.

```
std::stringstream  stream(str);
std::string        oneWord;

stream >> oneWord; // Reads one space separated word.
```

When can use this to count words in a string.

```
std::stringstream  stream(str);
std::string        oneWord;
unsigned int       count = 0;

while(stream >> oneWord) { ++count;}
// count now has the number of words in the string.
```

Getting complicated:
Streams can be treated just like any other container and there are iterators to loop through them std::istream_iterator. When you use the ++ operator on an istream_iterator it just read the next value from the stream using the operator >>. In this case we are reading std::string so it reads a space separated word.

```
std::stringstream  stream(str);
std::string        oneWord;
unsigned int       count = 0;

std::istream_iterator loop = std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream);
std::istream_iterator end  = std::istream_iterator<std::string>();

for(;loop != end; ++count, ++loop) { *loop; }
```

Using std::distance just wraps all the above in a tidy package as it find the distance between two iterators by doing ++ on the first until we reach the second.

To avoid copying the string we can be sneaky:

```
unsigned int countWordsInString(std::string const& str)
{
    std::stringstream stream;

    // sneaky way to use the string as the buffer to avoid copy.
    stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf (str.c_str(), str.length() );
    return std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}
```

Note: we still copy each word out of the original into a temporary. But the cost of that is minimal.

Comment: Would +1 for cleverness but out of votes -- note however that this results in copying the underlying string at least twice as well as several memory allocations, plus several virtual function calls as a result of running on top of iostreams.

Comment: @ Billy ONeal: True. But I bet for a string under 1K it is indistinguishable in time over just one run. Plus it is so easy to read and understand that I am willing to pay this cost.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Added sneaky way to avoid the main string copy. Copying each word into a temporary string has minimal cost.

Comment: *Easy to read* for whom?  The author or the unknown maintainer?  (It could be that a place of employ demands that folks know the C++ standard library, but I have yet to be employed by such a facility. :) )  (Note that I think this is a neat solution, but have been so far away from proper C++ for so long that it'd take me by surprise to run across it.)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: Err.. it's unreasonable to ask for a C++ programmer and expect them not to know C++. The standard library is a part of C++.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: I hope it is easy for anybody to read. The whole point of a standard library is that everybody use rather than inventing their own. Thus even if you did not know about distance you could look it up in twenty seconds see it us using iterators deduce that we were iterating across a stream and bobs your uncle. Code deduced in 30 seconds.

Comment: My "objection" is only to the implication that every company has the same needs and requirements as your own.  My industry typically uses a very strict subset of C++, and it is surprising to find anyone who knows `<algorithm>` at all, much less in overview.  "Standard library" in my industry means "probably useful to people with different requirements than ours."

Comment: Note that `setbuf` with nonzero arguments is implementation-defined for all standard `streambuf` classes including `stringbuf`. It might maybe work with all SGI-derived iostreams, but… `strstream` is probably more portable.

Comment: Martin, thank for the very detailed answer, but I don't think this was what the interviewer had in mind. It may very well be much better than the other solutions but only the c++ rockstars are gone grok this, which i can assure you my interviewer was not (and neither am I for that matter)

Comment: @eviljack: Different interviews are different.. When I was shopping around in Manhattan some 5 years ago, in some places the basic trivia questions included things like "what is Koenig lookup?" and "when are streambuf iterators better than stream iterators?".

Comment: This is the kind of question I ask to find out if the interview does know the STL. A good candidate will do this (or at least use streams to split the input into words (as that is very common)). The best ones will use std::distanace() the good ones will use a loop the ones we don't hire will be the ones that parse a word by themselves.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the std::count or std::count_if to do that. Below a simple example with std::count:

```
//Count the number of words on string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> //count and count_if is declared here

int main () {
    std::string sTEST("Text to verify how many words it has.");

    std::cout << std::count(sTEST.cbegin(), sTEST.cend(), ' ')+1;

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: Due the observation made by Aydin Özcan (Nov 16) I made a change to this solution. Now the words may have more than one space between them. :)

```
//Count the number of words on string
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::string T("Text to   verify :  How many words does it   have?");

    size_t NWords = T.empty() || T.back() == ' ' ? 0 : 1;
    for (size_t s = T.size(); s > 0; --s)
        if (T[s] == ' ' && T[s-1] != ' ') ++NWords;

    std::cout << NWords;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not work when there are multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 5):

Another boost based solution that may work (untested):

```
vector<string> result;
split(result, "aaaa bbbb cccc", is_any_of(" \t\n\v\f\r"), token_compress_on);
```

More information can be found in the [Boost String Algorithms Library](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/string_algo.html)

Comment: While it works, it's not exactly what I'd be looking for in an interview.

Comment: Why not?  Unless the interviewer specifically asks for an implementation that doesn't use a large amount of temporary storage, or that it shouldn't use boost, then I think this is a very acceptable answer.  It's certainly the most readable of all of the offered solutions and I think is a good example of idiomatic C++.

Comment: I would also probably go on to ask them how they might implement it without using a vector of strings and without boost.  A good candidate would be able to offer both kinds of solution.

Comment: "While it works, it's not exactly what I'd be looking for in an interview." - you mean you'd be looking for someone then who wants to always writes things the long way. ;-) It would be useful to me for you to elaborate on your comment.

Answer (score 4):

An O(N) solution that is also very simple to understand and implement:

(I haven't checked for an empty string input. But I am sure you can do that easily.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int countNumberOfWords(string sentence){
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    size_t i;

    if (isalpha(sentence[0])) {
        numberOfWords++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if ((isalpha(sentence[i])) && (!isalpha(sentence[i-1]))) {
            numberOfWords++;
        }
    }

    return numberOfWords;
}

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    cout<<"Enter the sentence : ";
    getline(cin, sentence);

    int numberOfWords = countNumberOfWords(sentence);
    cout<<"The number of words in the sentence is : "<<numberOfWords<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without manually looking at every character or copying the string.

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <cctype>

boost::transform_iterator
    < int (*)(int), std::string::const_iterator, bool const& >
    pen( str.begin(), std::isalnum ), end( str.end(), std::isalnum );

size_t word_cnt = 0;

while ( pen != end ) {
    word_cnt += * pen;
    pen = std::mismatch( pen+1, end, pen ).first;
}

return word_cnt;
```

I took the liberty of using `isalnum` instead of `isspace`.

This is not something I would do at a job interview. (It's not like it compiled the first time.)

Or, for all the Boost haters ;v)

```
if ( str.empty() ) return 0;

size_t word_cnt = std::isalnum( * str.begin() );

for ( std::string::const_iterator pen = str.begin(); ++ pen != str.end(); ) {
    word_cnt += std::isalnum( pen[ 0 ] ) && ! std::isalnum( pen[ -1 ] );
}

return word_cnt;
```

Comment: Also, everything except `size_t word_cnt…` and `return…` could go inside a `for` loop.

Comment: This answer is impressive, but basically unreadable, and requires an unwieldy 3rd party library notorious for exploding build times. If someone attempted this on an interview I'd probably pass on them.

Comment: Yeah the isalnum vs isspace is a question open due to the ambiguous nature of the OP's post; I parsed it as "punctuation is not a space so it counts as a word character."

Comment: @blucz: With a few comments, it wouldn't be so bad, since the job of the `transform_iterator` is pretty straightforward. Using `mismatch` to find state transitions is generally useful. Some C++ programmers are also picky about whether lighter-weight Boost components are allowed…

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single pass, branchless (almost), locale-aware algorithm which handles cases with more than one space between words:

> 1. If the string is empty return 0
> 2. let transitions = number of adjacent char pairs (c1, c2) where `c1 == ' '` and `c2 != ' '`
> 3. if the sentence starts with a space, return `transitions` else return `transitions + 1`

Here is an example with string = "A very, very, very, very, very big dog ate my homework!!!!"

```
 i | 0123456789
c1 | A very, very, very, very, very big dog ate my homework!!!!
c2 |  A very, very, very, very, very big dog ate my homework!!!!
   |  x     x     x     x     x    x   x   x   x  x
```

**Explanation**

```
Let `i` be the loop counter.

When i=0: c1='A' and c2=' ', the condition `c1 == ' '` and `c2 != ' '` is not met
When i=1: c1=' ' and c2='A', the condition is met
... and so on for the remaining characters
```

Here are 2 solutions I came up with

**Naive solution**

```
size_t count_words_naive(const std::string_view& s)
{
    if (s.size() == 0) return 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    bool isspace1, isspace2 = true;
    for (auto c : s) {
        isspace1 = std::exchange(isspace2, isspace(c));
        count += (isspace1 && !isspace2);
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you think carefully, you will be able to reduce this set of operations into an inner product (just for fun, I don't recommend this as this is arguably much less readable).

**Inner product solution**

```
size_t count_words_using_inner_prod(const std::string_view& s)
{
    if (s.size() == 0) return 0;
    auto starts_with_space = isspace(s.front());
    auto num_transitions = std::inner_product(
            s.begin()+1, s.end(), s.begin(), 0, std::plus<>(),
            [](char c2, char c1) { return isspace(c1) && !isspace(c2); });
    return num_transitions + !starts_with_space;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## I think that will help

#### the complexty O(n)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int count = 0, size;
    string sent;

    getline(cin, sent);

    size = sent.size();
```

check if the char is in alpha and the next char not in alpha

```
     for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) { 
       if (isalpha(sent[i]) && !isalpha(sent[i+1])) { 
            ++count;
        }
     }
```

if the word in the last of sentence didn't count above so it count here

```
     if (isalpha(sent[size - 1]))++count;

    cout << count << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This  code will fail on non-English texts (e.g. UTF-8 strings).

Answer (score 0):

A very concise O(N) approach:

```
bool is_letter(char c) { return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'; }

int count_words(const string& s) {
    int i = 0, N = s.size(), count = 0;
    while(i < N) {
        while(i < N && !is_letter(s[i])) i++;
        if(i == N) break;
        while(i < N && is_letter(s[i])) i++;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

A divide-and-conquer approach, complexity is also O(N):

```
int DC(const string& A, int low, int high) {
    if(low > high) return 0;
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

    int count_left = DC(A, low, mid-1);
    int count_right = DC(A, mid+1, high);

    if(!is_letter(A[mid])) 
        return count_left + count_right;
    else {
        if(mid == low && mid == high) return 1;
        if(mid-1 < low) {
            if(is_letter(A[mid+1])) return count_right;
            else return count_right+1;
        } else if(mid+1 > high) {
            if(is_letter(A[mid-1])) return count_left;
            else return count_left+1;
        }
        else {
            if(!is_letter(A[mid-1]) && !is_letter(A[mid+1])) 
                return count_left + count_right + 1;
            else if(is_letter(A[mid-1]) && is_letter(A[mid+1]))
                return count_left + count_right - 1;
            else
                return count_left + count_right;
        }
    }
}

int count_words_divide_n_conquer(const string& s) {
    return DC(s, 0, s.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient version based on map-reduce approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <numeric>

std::size_t CountWords(std::string_view s) {
    if (s.empty())
        return 0;

    std::size_t wc = (!std::isspace(s.front()) ? 1 : 0);
    wc += std::transform_reduce(
        s.begin(),
        s.end() - 1,
        s.begin() + 1,
        std::size_t(0),
        std::plus<std::size_t>(),
                [](char left, char right) {
        return std::isspace(left) && !std::isspace(right);
    });

    return wc;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << CountWords("  pretty  little octopus "sv) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```