# Counting the number of words in a string, C++

Tags: c++, string, counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ function to count all the words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672234/c-function-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-string)

So I have a line of words which i stored in a string using C++. i.e. "There was a farmer named Billy\n"

I want to know the number of words in the string (i.e. There are currently 6 words in it). Can  anyone tell me how to do this? If this is not possible is there a way I can count the number of spaces in the string (i.e. " "). Let me know THanks!

Comment: Check out this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672234/c-function-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-string

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes I did was wondering if there were any built in functions for doing this. Havent found anything

Comment: what is your definition of "word"? can you use regex?

Comment: Word as in a word like "farmer" or "Billy"

Comment: +1 to wiso. As soon as you dangle any non-alpha char past one or more whitespace all the stream-extraction solutions below fall on their face. easily fixed by checking the first char with isalpha(), (well, closer anyway, but still). Is this all the OP has to work with?

Comment: yes that is all i have to work with

Comment: That being the case, if you're *confident* the input is strictly alphanumeric-leading sequences separated by whitespace (or eof), any of the below will work fine.

Answer (score 9):

A simple way to count the words is by using the >> operator with std::string, like this:

```
std::stringstream is("There was a farmer named Billy");
std::string word;

int number_of_words = 0;
while (is >> word)
  number_of_words++;
```

When extracting a std::string from an std::istream the >>operator() will in its default settings skip whitespace which means it will give you each 'word' separated by one or more spaces. So the above code will give you the same result even if the words are separated by more than one space.

Comment: This is terribly slow for such thing.

Comment: @KirilKirov: yes it is terribly slow, but it does what is requested with few lines of code :)

Comment: True, that's why I didn't down-vote :)

Answer (score 9):

Sure, it's simple:

```
std::cout << "number of words: "
          << std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(
                               std::istringstream(str) >> std::ws),
                           std::istream_iterator<std::string>()) << '\n';
```

Just for a bit of explanation:

1. Reading a `std::string` reads a word after skiping leading whitespace where a *word* is a sequence of non-whitespace characters.
2. `std::istream_iterator<T>` turns an input stream into a sequence of `T` objects by reading corresponding objects until reading fails.
3. `std::istringstream` takes a `std::string` and turns it into a stream being read from.
4. The constructor argument to `std::istream_iterator<T>` is `std::istream&`, i.e., the temporary `std::istringstream` can't be used directly but a reference needs to be obtained. This is the only interesting effect of `std::ws` which also skips leading whitespace.
5. `std::distance()` determines how many elements are in a sequence (the originally used `std::count()` determines how many elements in the sequence match a given condition but hte condition was actually missing).

Comment: :D That's not simple for a beginner, but +1, I like it.

Comment: can you explain this a bit further?

Comment: shouldn't this actually be std::distance()?

Comment: @mauve: good point: it should be `std::distance()` rather than `std::count()`. I'll fix the code.