# C++ Homework - Counting words

Tags: c++, pointers, count, words

So I'm making a program where it lets you input a sentence and the program counts how many words there in the sentence. I cant seem to get the program to let me input the string.  Do I need to include the pointer in the cin?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int stringsize(char*);
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* cstring;  //pointer
    cout << " Please enter phrase to count number of words: ";
    cin.get(cstring);
    int numofwords;
    numofwords = stringsize(cstring);
    cout << numofwords << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

int stringsize(char* cstr)
{
    int pos,sizeofstr;
    sizeofstr = 0;
    string copy;
    string cplusstr(cstr);
    while ((pos = cplusstr.find(' ')) != -1)
    {
        pos = cplusstr.find(' ');
        copy.assign(cplusstr,0,pos);
        cplusstr.erase(0,pos+1);
        copy.erase(0,pos);
        sizeofstr = sizeofstr + 1;
    }
    int length = cplusstr.size();
    char* cstring = new char[length + 1];
    strcpy(cstring,cplusstr.c_str());
    if(cstring != NULL) //no whitespace left but there is still a word
    {
        sizeofstr = sizeofstr + 1;
    }
    return sizeofstr;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I cant seem to get the program to let me input the string.`? What happens when you try to give it input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ function to count all the words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672234/c-function-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string` instead of `char*`. By the way in your actual code, pointer is not initialized to point to any valid memory locations.

```
std::string phrase;
cin >> phrase;
```

And pass it to the functions like `phrase.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not allocating memory for the pointer and you aren't even initializing it.

```
char* cstring = new char[256];
```

That should fix it.

Afterwards you would `delete[] cstring;` to deallocate the allocated memory.

---

Anyway, this is C++, so you should try to avoid `char*` and use `std::string` at all times. Performance isn't going to vary much at all, and in this case, it wouldn't even matter.

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
int numofwords = stringsize(str.c_str());
```