# C++ How to identify the number of words by spaces using a function

Tags: c++

I need to make a function that identifies the number of words by spaces (Ignoring trailing and leading ones). I'm having trouble with the equation that recognizes a space within the string variable. It doesn't count a space like it should. I should be getting the number "2" with the test case I have.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void numWords(string phrase)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < phrase.length(); index++)

        int words = 0;
            int space = 0;

    if (phrase[index] == ' ')
    {
        words++;
        space++;
    }
}

if (space == 0) //This is for single words with no spaces 
{
    words++;
}
cout << words << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string phrase;
    int words = 0;

    numWords("hello, world");
    //A test case

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble " you need to be more specific. You get a compile error? You get a runtime error? You get no errors but you get unexpected results? If you get errors post them. If you get unexpected results post them.

Comment: It might help you to read about [fencepost errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).

Comment: `int words, space = 0;` Variable `words` is not initialized.

Comment: "It doesn't count a space like it should." It doesn't even compile ...

Comment: Your indentation was lying to you. I've edited the question so indentation properly reflects your actual scopes.

Comment: @Galik I initialized them individually like you suggested but I'm getting the default "1" output when the test case has 2 words.

Comment: What lines do you think your for loops over?

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code / your approach:

1. You haven't initialized the number of words.
2. You count words and spaces the exact same way - but they're not the same.
3. You haven't properly defined what's a word:

   - Does the empty string contain a word?
   - If a space delimits words, is there an empty word between two consecutive spaces?
   - What about punctuation marks, do they count as parts of words?
   - What about non-printing characters?

So, there's little wonder your output doesn't satisfy your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

check the solution of  "dash-tom-bang" in :
[C++ function to count all the words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672234/c-function-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-string)

a Copy of it

```
#include <cctype>

int CountWords(const char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL)
    return error_condition;  // let the requirements define this...

    bool inSpaces = true;
    int numWords = 0;

    while (*str != NULL)
    {
        if (std::isspace(*str))
        {
            inSpaces = true;
        }
        else if (inSpaces)
        {
           numWords++;
           inSpaces = false;
        }

        ++str;
    }

    return numWords;
}
```