# Create program to find a text from given .txt file , replace and count the words

Tags: c++

my teacher ask me to create this program but I only know how to do B task .
He gave me a sample text and tell me to input it then do some actions (below). I looked up for task A but he said that we need to do the code like this.
I spent days for the book "C++ from controls Structures through Objects" which he required for the course but I cannot find the chapter that relates to "FIND STRING".

```
string text = "The aa Art of Computer Programming";
    int pos = 0;
    string target = "aa";

    pos = text.find(target, 0);

    }
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to change  `pos = text.find(target, 0);` => `pos = "input file ?".find(target,0)`.

> a. Search a text. The program receives the search-word from a user, searches the content of the file
>   and returns whether matching words are found or not and how many.
>
> b. Search and replace a text. The program reads the search-word and the replacement-word from a
>   user and it replaces the matching words in the content of the file with replacement-word.
>
> c. Determines the number of words.
>
> d. Determine the number of characters—including white-space

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string strTarget = " "; //String to search
    string strNew = " ";    //String To re
    ifstream filein("test.txt"); //File to read from
    ofstream fileout("replaced.txt"); //Temporary file
    int pos = 0;


    int menuItem = 0;
    cout << "What do you want to do today ?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Search a text " << endl;
    cout << "2. Search and replace the text " << endl;
    cout << "3. Determine number of word" << endl;
    cout << "4. Determine number of character " << endl;
    cin >> menuItem;



    switch (menuItem)
    {
    case 1:// search
        system("cls");
        cout << "Please enter the text you want to search" << endl;
        cin >> strTarget;

        break;

    case 2: // search and replace


        cout << " Tell me the text you want to replace " << endl;
        cin >> strTarget;
        cout << " So what It's suppose to be ? " << endl;
        cin >> strNew;

        if (!filein || !fileout) //if both files are not available
        {
            cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        string strTemp;
        //bool found = false;
        while (filein >> strTemp)//it will check line from test to strTemp string
        {
            if (strTemp == strTarget)//if your word found then replace
            {
                strTemp = strNew;
                //found = true;
            }
            strTemp += " ";
            fileout << strTemp;//output everything to fileout(temp.txt)
            //if(found) break;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

- the notes of the code is not really correct cause I change the name a little bit..
  i know this kinda ridiculous to most programmers but I'm new to CS and surething I have trouble with any code out of the book. please help me instead of being rude. Big thanks!
  i wish my college had tutor of CS but somehow they cannot afford a cs tutor. That's why i need help from you guys .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. What are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking for help , someone can give me an example or a link that I can learn cause I'm new to CS and my teacher gave me something out of the book content. and I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Task A: [Count character occurrences in a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867890/count-character-occurrences-in-a-string-in-c)
Task B: [How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)
Task C: [C++ function to count all the words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672234/c-function-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-string)

for the last task you just iterate over all characters in the string until you hit a null character, incrementing a counter each time.